# Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controller in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm using the Fosuserbundle to manager members in my project { **SF::3.4.8** }, 
when trying to override the controller of the registrationController by following the Symfony documentation

```
<?php

namespace TestUserBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOSUserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController {

    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        die("Hello");
    }
}
```

but the system ignore that controller and still use The original controller, so if there any way to override my controller by

Comment: Is your bundle child bundle of  `FOSUserBundle`?

Comment: have you defined registration route for this action same to fos_user registration route as it's said in symfony docs?

Comment: yes but i'm using symfony 3.4 so it will be ignored as said inthe symfony docs

Comment: note that "Bundle inheritance is deprecated since Symfony 3.4"

Comment: try to debug your routes using cli command https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/debug.html to see if your registration path matches your custom registration route

Comment: @PavelAlazankin i know for that i'm looking for new solution

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek child Fosuserbundle is deprecated since SF3.4

Comment: OK, what behavior / feature do you want to achieve? Maybe you don't need to override controller.

Answer (score 1):

First, overriding the controller is probably not the best way to process. You should consider to *hook* into controller. Here is the related documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

Then if you still want to override the controller, you should act in the dependency injection. The service name of the controller is `fos_user.registration.controller`.

To replace the service you can simply use:

```
services:
    fos_user.registration.controller: 
        class: YourController
        arguments:
            $eventDispatcher: '@event_dispatcher'
            $formFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
            $userManager: '@fos_user.user_manager'
            $tokenStorage: 'security.token_storage'
```

---

You can also override it in a [CompilerPass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html). Which is probably the best solution for you because you do this inside another bundle.

Here is how it should look:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class ReplaceRegistrationController extends CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->getDefinition('fos_user.registration.controller')
            ->setClass(YourController::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [register it inside your bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html#working-with-compiler-passes-in-bundles):

```
$container->addCompilerPass(new ReplaceRegistrationController());
```

Comment: What version do you use ?

Comment: "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
 "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",