# Symfony FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to redeclare FOSUserBundle ProfileController, but when I am doing it nothing changes. I have followed the instruction https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html
and created:
/src/UserBundle/UserBundle.php

```
    <?php

namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
  }
}
```

and 
/src/UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;


class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
  public function editAction(Request $request)
  {
    var_dump("I am HERE");exit();

    return $request;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong could somebody give an advise?

Comment: note that "Bundle inheritance is deprecated since Symfony 3.4" and also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917021/overriding-default-fosuserbundle-controller-in-symfony-3-4

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3 you don't use bundle inheritance anymore as @Pavel Alazankin already pointed out.
To override FOSUser controllers you need to:

1. remove the function getParent() inside your USerBundle
2. find out which routes are used by FOSUserBundle [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml) and override them in your controller

> ```
> <?php namespace UserBundle\Controller;
>
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
> use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;
> use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
> use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
> use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
>
> class ProfileController extends BaseController {
>
>  public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher,
>      FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
>  {
>      parent::__construct($eventDispatcher, $formFactory, $userManager);
>  }
>
> /**
>  * override FOSUserBundle
>  * @param Request $request
>  *
>  * @Route(
>  *      "/login",
>  *      name="fos_user_profile_edit"
>  *  )
>  * @Method("GET|POST")
>  *
>  * @return Response
>  */
>  public function editAction(Request $request)
>  {
>     var_dump("I am HERE");exit();
>
>     return $request;
> }
> ```

Comment: Using yours I get this error:
"Too few arguments to function FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/webapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 195 and exactly 3 expected."
The only way it works if I make it as @Pavel suggested by redefining it as service then I gat all 3 parameters for construct, but how to obtain them using your method?